# Alternative to ANOVA (beginner)

Tags: anova, normal-distribution, variance, nonparametric, multilevel-analysis

I have run 15 experiments to compare the effect of different hormone combinations on the maturation on Xenopus oocytes (immature eggs). I am hoping to find the best performing variable.

I have 4 hormone conditions:

(1) Progesterone

(2) IGF-1

(3) Both

(4) No hormone

I have 7 treatment groups:

(1) 1 µM Progesterone

(2) 5 µM Progesterone

(3) 100 nM IGF-1

(4) 200 nM IGF-1

(5) 100 nM IGF-1 + 1 µM Progesterone (Both)

(6) 200 nM IGF-1 + 1 µM Progesterone (Both)

(7) No hormone

There are 15 tests for each treatment group and the results are % maturation (the amount of eggs which matured by counting a white dot).

For treatment groups 3, 4 and 7 I observed 0% maturation in all oocytes. Therefore running  classical ANOVA is difficult and the data assumes unequal variance. I am unable to run unequal variance tests in SPSS when using all the groups as they cannot compute 0.

The data is not normally distributed either. Would it be sensible just to run non-parametric Willcoxon tests on appropriate treatment groups (e.g. progesterone against progesterone) to compare one another. Each test was conducted at the same time for each treatment group?

I was hoping to compare the best performing hormone and treatment combination i.e. comparing Progesterone against IGF-1, combination and no hormone and to compare the different concentrations. Any advice would be appreciated as I am a beginner when it comes to statistics and SPSS.  Thank you !!

Comment: What kind of data is your response variable? Is it a count of matured out of a total number of cells? Is it an unscaled count? Is it a continuous percentage? Something else?

Comment: `%` sounds as a _continuous response_, even a _ration_. However, if your ratios are like _3 out of 5_, you might as well look at it as a _categorical_ or two _ordinal_ outcome. So, question, what is the distribution of your outcome? (In SAS, that is the result of a `proc freq` with `table denominator * numerator;`)

Comment: % is just the amount of eggs which matured over eggs which didn't around 150 for each treatment

Comment: When you say that you have 15 tests for each treatment group, does that mean that you have 15 groups of eggs, or 15 eggs? So do you have 15 "yes/no" data, or do you have 15 "% fertilized data"? Can you give us a snapshot of the what your data look like?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the OP has not responded to questions that are needed for an answer.